# Windows NT workstation on AD domain

Tags: active-directory, login, legacy, windows

We run a Windows NT workstation connected to special manufacturing equipment, that everyone is deathly afraid to touch. It has custom software and special cards inside of the machine, making a rebuild impossible. The problem is, we are migrating to an AD domain from an NT domain, and this workstation stills needs access to storage on the network (AD computers). How should I go about doing this, after we get rid of our NT Domain controller? Upgrading to 2000 is not an option (so says management).

I know, I know, if it dies we are in trouble. But that's managements choice, we just need to get rid of this NT domain.

Comment: OT: You should definitely use Acronis or some other imaging software to get an image of that NT4 server *BEFORE* it dies.  We have some of the same legacy issues in my environment, and you *CANNOT* assume you will be able to restore this kind of legacy system from a regular backup.  You should also review and *TEST* the procedures for restoring NT4 to "unlike hardware" as it is a rather painful procedure.  FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows NT can work perfectly fine as a member computer in an Active Directory domain.

Comment: Yes, the NT4 workstation will talk to AD via whichever domain controller holds the PDC Emulator fsmo role.

Comment: I'd plan on arranging for good NetBIOS name resolution. If your DC holding the PDC emulator token is off-subnet from the NT 4 machine you may need to use WINS.

Comment: He probably already has WINS in place, if this is the case; good point, anyway.